# Python, aiogram, как можно проверить добавил ли пользователь кого-то в бота?

Tags: python, aiogram

В общем у меня есть телеграм бот, и я хочу реализовать в нем некую систему уровней.

Я видел что некоторые боты просят пригласить друзей, дают инлайн кнопку и после этого проверяют добавил ли user друзей.

Конкретно я хочу добавить например три уровня бота, которые немного расширяют возможности для пользователя. И  когда пользователь хочет повысить себе уровень ему будет приходить сообщение добавить например 5 друзей!

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать проверку добавил ли user друзей (возможно нужна специальная ссылка для старта?)

Comment: Вы сами пытались решить данную задачу? Есть с вашей стороны примеры? Если да, лучше приложите к задаче. Так будет проще дать вам ответ.

Comment: Используйте deep-linking, формируйте индивидуальный ключ для пользователей, и считайте переходы